# Pass a JS variable to a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have a JavaScript value given by Google maps and I need to save it in a MySQL database.

Actually I have the variable

```
<script>
...
var lugar = results[0].geometry.location;// this gives me a latitud, longitud value, like: -34.397, 150.644
...
</script>
```

And I need to pass that variable to the PHP variable lugar

```
<?
$lugar= ?????
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: @dbaseman Given the antique answer from the duplicate, perhaps it should be the other way around? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `POST` through a form or pass it in the URL if you're doing it on page transition, then just use `$_POST` or `$_GET` to receive the variable.

If you need it done seamlessly then you might want to look at using AJAX.
[TIZAG AJAX Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php)

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery ajax for this, but you need to create another script that save on your database:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "save.in.my.database.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType:"json",
    data: {
        lugar: results[0].geometry.location
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('saved');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
</script>
```

"save.in.my.database.php" receives a `$_POST['lugar']` and you can save on your database.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass it via a form submission, cookie, or through a querystring.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

This will convert js variable to php variable

```
<script>
function sud(){

javavar=document.getElementById("text").value;  

document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML="<?php 
$phpvar='"+javavar+"'; 
echo $phpvar.$phpvar;?>";
}

function sud2(){
document.getElementById("rslt2").innerHTML="<?php 
echo $phpvar;?>";
}

</script> 
<body>
<div id="rslt">
</div>

<div id="rslt2">
</div>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<button onClick="sud()" >Convert</button>
<button onClick="sud2()">Once Again</button>

</body>
```

Demo: http://ibence.com/new.php