# Convert Javascript variable to PHP from console.log(response)

Tags: php, facebook, json

I have a script to send friend request by Request Dialog

```
function requestCallback(response)
{
    if(response && response.request)
    {
        console.log(response);
        location.href='step2.php';
    }
    else
    {   
        location.href='step1.php';
    }
}
```

The console.log(response) outputs in Firefox's console :

```
({request:THIS_IS_REQUEST_ID, to:[REQUESTED_USER_ID_1, REQUESTED_USER_ID_2, REQUESTED_USER_ID_ETC...]})
```

How I can convert the variable `console.log(response);` to PHP variable?

Because I need the values like `REQUESTED_USER_ID_1, REQUESTED_USER_ID_2` JSON output from the `console.log(response);` to be parsed by PHP's json_decode, [like this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4854074/how-to-grab-the-json-returned-value-in-php).

Thanks!

Comment: You need to read up on AJAX to pass the data back to PHP via an asynchronous call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716177/pass-a-js-variable-to-a-php-variable

Comment: Search your question's title on Stack Overflow. There are many many comparable questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot actually convert them into PHP variable, but what you can do is that you can send the REQUESTED_USER_ID1...IDn to the php file that you are setting as location.href as a HTTP GET parameter in this way.

```
function requestCallback(response)
{
    if(response && response.request)
    {
        console.log(response);
        location.href='step2.php?ids='+response.to.join(",");
    }
    else
    {   
        location.href='step1.php';
    }
}
```

And then in your php file step2.php, you can get those user ids in this way

```
<?php
$userids = explode(",",$_GET['ids']);
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it works! By the way, I am curious why it must named `response.to.join`. I use other name but it does not work.

Comment: I now this comment is late, but I just came across this post.  There isn't anything named "response.to.join".  "response" is an object with a property "to" that is an array of ids.  Then the "join" function is called in order to join all the values of the array using a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_POST) the [JSON-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) object to your server.