# how to pass javascript jQuery variable value in php array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

For example

```
var dirnm = jQuery.trim($('#dirname').val());
var parent1 = jQuery.trim($('#parent').val());

var url = '<?=$this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'dirnameex','dirname'=>dirnm ,'parent'=>parent1))?>';
```

`dirnm` and `parent1` are a ajax variables.
So I want to pass `dirnm` and `parent1` to a php array.

Comment: this wont work JavaScript is executed in the browser and PHP executed on the server - you need to POST the variables from JavaScript to PHP and `dirnm` and `parent1` are JavaScript variables on AJAX variables ... [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is a technique not a language

Comment: You will need to use ajax to send variables from AJAX to PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass a js variable to a php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716177/pass-a-js-variable-to-a-php-variable)

Answer (score 1):

This wont work as JavaScript is executed in the browser and PHP executed on the server .. so the PHP would be executed before the page is loaded in the browser and the JavaScript executed ....

What you could do is `POST` the variables to PHP :

```
var dirnm = jQuery.trim($('#dirname').val());
var parent1 = jQuery.trim($('#parent').val());
$.post("sript.php", { dirname: dirnm, parent: parent1 } );
```

then in PHP (`script.php`) :

```
// get the variables from $_POST
$dir = $_POST['dirname'];
$par = $_POST['parent'];
$this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'dirnameex','dirname'=> $dir,'parent'=> $par))
```

[Docs here for $.post() (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [Docs here for $_POST (PHP)](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Thanks ManseUK but this code in jquery & javascript for focusout event. so can i do?

Comment: just put the JavaScript code within the focusout callback - `$('#yourid').focusout(function() { // here });`

Comment: actually i got this value using JavaScript code within the focusout callback. but i want pass this value to php array

Comment: @user1312776 i dont understand your request ... update you question with the full code and explain what you want to happen ... both PHP and JavaScript

Comment: how to pass javascript jQuery variable value in php array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382968/how-to-pass-javascript-jquery-variable-value-in-php-array Please check this link

Answer (score 0):

php runs server side, javascript runs client side so you can't do that.

You can pass the variables to php using ajax. but this would be a seperate thread.