# Post result from javascript to variable

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass a js variable to a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716177/pass-a-js-variable-to-a-php-variable)

I have this code

```
  {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            alert("Current position: " + lat + " " + lng);
        }
```

I want to post the alert to a php variable like this

```
$location = above result
```

How can i accomplish this?  Thank you

Comment: the result is the lat and longitude of location from browser

Comment: Do you want to set a variable with this value?

Comment: Yes i do want to set a variable.  So $location would be the coordinates

Comment: Edit the question here instead posting it again ([with the missing infomration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11583175/367456)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an ajax call to your server.

```
$.post(server, {lat: lat, lng:lng})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass directly from javascript to PHP.
If you want to do so, use AJAX, or just make your calculation in PHP first :)