# Pass variables from Javascript to PHP - Popup/Modal Window

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, modal-dialog

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showdivv(el, idclicked) {
                var iddd = idclicked;
                var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
                if(display == "none")
                    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
                else
                    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
        <?php  $showw = "<script>document.write(iddd)</script>"; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" style="display: none;">ID Selected: <?php echo $showw; ?></div>
    <?php $variable = 4; ?>
    <button type="button" onclick="showdivv('myDiv', '<?php echo $variable; ?>')">Show / Hide</button>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make a way when a person presses the button pass the variable, in this case ID, to JavaScript and then show the hidden div in PHP. It does not work, can someone help me? THX

Comment: Please post a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a JS variable to a PHP variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716177/pass-a-js-variable-to-a-php-variable)

Comment: Can you send me the solution please, in code? THX

Comment: The problem is: this: <?php echo $showw; ?> dont show

Comment: You do not seem to understand the difference between server side code and client side code. If you want to pass a variable from javascript to php, you're going to have to do it via an html form or via an XMLHttprequest (aka ajax)

Comment: Can you send me the solution in code please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with the page reloading, you can simply do

```
window.location.href('php_script_that_needs_your_input.php?id=input_id_from_js');
```

If not, I absolutely recommend using JQuery as it makes Ajax queries a breeze.

Inside the `<head>` tags:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'></script>
```

Upload the script to your own server for production purposes, obviously.

in the `<body>`, where you want the results from the PHP script to appear (skip this if you don't want output from PHP):

```
<div id="phpResult"><!--content to be set by ajax--></div>
```

and put this JS directly below this `<div>`:

```
function ajax_on_button_press(resultDiv, id) {
   var phpUrl = "php_script.php?id="+id+"&other_variable=cheese&more_info=rats";
   $(resultDiv).load(phpUrl);
}
```

I have used example values here, but you can easily use variables from JavaScript like this:

```
var other_variable=$('#otherVariableInput').val(); //gets input from a textbox with the html id otherVariableInput
var phpUrl = "php_script.php?id="+id+"&other_variable="+other_variable+"&more_info=rats";
```

To start the process, you need a button that runs this script. Change your button markup to

```
<button type="button" onclick="ajax_on_button_press('#phpResult', '<?php echo $variable; ?>')">Show / Hide</button>
```

If I have understood you correctly, that should solve your problem.